# replacing sequence id in a file to the new ids mentioned below

Tags: awk

i have a file that looks like this

```
unitig_1747    675
unitig_322     119    496
unitig_323     890    571    3178   50
unitig_320     50     3635
```

And I 'd like to modify like this

```
unitig_1747_1_675
unitig_322_1_119    
unitig_322_2_496
unitig_323_1_890
unitig_323_2_571
unitig_323_3_3178
unitig_323_4_50
unitig_320_1_50
unitig_320_2_3635
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you tried so far. Otherwise, this is likely to be closed as _gimme my code_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner does it:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s_%d_%s\n",$1,i-1,$i}' file
```

It outputs:

```
unitig_1747_1_675
unitig_322_1_119
unitig_322_2_496
unitig_323_1_890
unitig_323_2_571
unitig_323_3_3178
unitig_323_4_50
unitig_320_1_50
unitig_320_2_3635
```

If your file is `TAB` separated, add `-F'\t'` after `awk`

Comment: thank you for answer @kent now i have another question which stackflow is not letting me post that is i have 2 files  file a which contains unitig_1036_1_5803 and file b unitig_1036_1   scaffold464_size30927   99.81   1029    2       0       1       1029    28149   29177   0.0     1976  i want to replace 1st column with "unitig_1036_1_5803" using awk help needed to solve this

Comment: Sorry @madhubioinfo I cannot understand your requirement from this poor format. I don't see any column. try asking another question if it is not a duplicate from this one. Also try to google something like "process mutiple files/ two files with awk" to get some idea how it works. And try a bit by yourself. Perhaps you don't need ask the other question any longer.